# What does :s (by itself) do?

Tags: substitute

What does `:s` by itself do? I was thinking that it would be equivalent to:

```
:s//
```

Does it use the equivalent of `<C-r>/` or something, or where is it grabbing the pattern from?

Comment: Why is this, and so many of your other questions, tagges [tag:vimrc]? What does the `:s` command have to do with vimrc?

Comment: @muru I. think mostly because I don't know how to tag it / what aspect of vim it is, other than `vimscript` I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per vim's help*, `:s` by itself,

> [Repeats the] last :substitute with same search pattern and
> substitute string, but without the same flags.

This means vim will perform substitution like this `:s/{pat}/{sub}/`, where `pat` is the last *substitute* pattern, which is not exactly (as the help may imply) the same as the last search pattern stored in `@/`.  To emphasize the part about flags, if you had used global substitute like `:s/a/b/g`, `:s` would *not* be done with global set.

In contrast, `s://` means use the last search pattern and replace with empty string.

Note the difference between `:s` and `:~`, which actually does use the last search pattern (like with `/`), which then becomes the last substitute pattern also.

*`:help :&`

Comment: is there a register or something that stores the last `{pat}` ? Or how do you see what that is?

Comment: There is: "\ holds the last search pattern.

Comment: @Wolf last search pattern and last substitute pattern are different.  There is no way to get the last substitute pattern as far as I know.